# What happens to my questions that are never answered?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I have 2 questions already that are viewed, but never answered/commented on, and it seems no one even cares to bother with them, I see that older questions just sort of getting thrown into a bin (metaphorically) and ignored. So my question is, is there a way for people to notice these questions, or are they completely forgotten? Heres the two if you'd like to see them:

1. [call function with dat.gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380707/how-do-i-call-a-function-using-dat-gui-like-a-button)
2. [javascript image effects connected to a video player/media file player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55924670/how-do-i-connect-an-image-effect-to-a-media-file-player)

Comment: It does not help to use low-quality English. It is unneeded friction, and you will irritate most of your readers.

Comment: I disagree with the downvotes on this question. This is a good meta question, well formulated and seeking input. It's as good as it gets. Non-negatively scored, unanswered questions just remain on the site, as far as I know. I don't think they are intentionally ignored. If I stumble across an unanswered, interesting question that I can answer, I do so regardless of the age of the question.

Answer (score 16):

First, make sure you've asked your question in such a way that makes it as answerable as possible. I am not an expert in JavaScript, but here are my general tips to ensure answerability is to the max:

1. Explain what you're trying to do
2. Explain what you've done and what hasn't worked. This would be a good place to insert a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
3. Add in one or more examples of your input and expected output.

If your question isn't immediately answered, that doesn't mean you're being deliberately ignored -- just that people who've seen your question thus far aren't confident enough, or lack the know-how to answer them. I've seen questions taking weeks, months, or even years before someone with the requisite knowledge came around to answer them, so just be patient.

If you cannot wait that long, you can always [place a bounty on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). You'll need [75 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to do so, however, so I suggest you get to answering some questions yourself!

Comment: Only debugging questions require minimal reproducible examples. How-to questions do not require code of any sort, nor do they require an attempt to solve the problem or any other evidence of effort solving the problem. If they show a lack of research effort they should be closed as a duplicate. If there is no duplicate then the question cannot possibly show a lack of research effort. How-to questions must be reasonably scoped (asking about 1 thing, not 5 things) and well-defined (they must be unambiguous, not open to interpretation).

Comment: @TinyGiant "If there is no duplicate then the question cannot possibly show a lack of research effort." That's one of the most ludicrous statements I've heard for a while. "How do I add two Int32 values in C#?" may not have a duplicate, but it certainly shows a lack of research effort. It may not be *closeable* for that reason, but that does not absolve the questioner's obvious lack of research.

Comment: @HereticMonkey no that's entirely the point. If you find such a question not useful then downvote it. Questions don't lack research effort because the answer is obvious to _you_, or even because the information may exist elsewhere on the internet. The only research that is relevant on Stack Overflow is research _on Stack Overflow_.

Comment: I guess we'll just have to disagree then, @TinyGiant. I feel that your standard will lower the quality of questions asked on the site to such a degree that it will drive away experts looking for interesting questions to answer and the site will suffer for it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey what tends to drive experts away more is when everyone insists that all questions must be garbage debugging questions, or must include so much research as to be rendered pointless. I want interesting questions to answer, not useless debugging questions or walls of text from people just trying to satisfy your outlandish research requirements.

Comment: @TinyGiant I take some umbrage with the word "outlandish". I'm not sure how you got to that from asking someone to research how to add two numbers in C#. Not to mention how you went from my insistence on showing a modicum of research effort to wanting "garbage debugging questions" (which are often garbage because they don't do research). In any case, I doubt we'll see eye to eye on this, so I will take my leave.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with both of these questions is that they are too broad.

You need to break them down into their component parts and solve for each part individually. Once you get to the more specific part that you cannot figure out, then ask about that.

Trying to cover too much ground can prevent you from receiving a useful answer, and can lead to your question being closed.

Comment: My questions are not broad, I specifically used the question wizard to make them, and Ive provided a detailed relation for all my information, along with data examples, and other such required fields.

Comment: The question wizard doesn't automatically mean a question actually meets our quality standards, @Taylor.  It can still be very broad, unclear, or any of the other close reasons.  Nothing in the wizard prevents you from asking such a question.

Comment: If its not to the quality you desire, then Im sorry, but thats the way I write.

Comment: @TaylorSpark the quality of your writing is fine, the problem is that both questions try to cover too much ground and need to be broken down into their component parts in order to be on-topic questions.

Comment: So in a way, because Im writing essays, with much more details than needed, it means its off topic?! This is generally confusing me....

Comment: No I stead of asking "how can I do all of these things" you should ask "how can I do this specific and well-defined **thing**". That's what I mean by covering too much ground and it being overly broad. @TaylorSpark